# Pass data to php through select event of jquery ui autocomplete field

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ui

I want that the following code pass var1,2 and 3 to the autofill.php so i can gather them using $_GET :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'autofill.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term : request.term,
                var : 3,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    select : function(event, ui) {
            //pass var1,var2,var3 to php file
    },
    autoFocus:true,
     minLength: 3
   });
});
    </script>
```

the "source : function" works very well i can pass the var = 3 that decides which function to execute from autofill.php but I can't manage to send the data I need on select.

Comment: point 1: var is reserved word javascript. in select function is example ui.item.label and ui.item.value

Comment: You will need to setup a PHP Script first. Will it accept GET or POST? What will it do with the data? Then you can define what the `select` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#name").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
      $.getJSON("autofill.php", { term: request.term, "var": 3 }, function(data){
        response(data);
      });
    },
    select : function(event, ui) {
      $.post("adddata.php", ui.item, function(data){
        console.log("Added", ui.item);
      });
    },
    autoFocus:true,
     minLength: 3
   });
});
```

This performs a GET when populating the Source. If an item is selected, it is then add performs a POST to a PHP script that can do something with it.